# Fastboot devices not showing device

Tags: android, adb, fastboot

I am trying to unlock bootloader on my Samsung A40 with Android software tools. I have installed software tools through Android SDK Manager in Android Studio.
Adb lists devices:

[image]

However when I enter bootloader by typing `adb reboot bootloader` my device doesn't show with command fastboot devices:

[image]

I have tried installing drivers from Samsung site and through Android Studio Google drivers but neither worked. I installed drivers manually through device manager too.

I tried doing same commands in VM with Debian 10 but with same result.

I have tried flashing TWRP with Odin too but I got error: custom binary (vbmeta) blocked by oem lock.

I tried different USB ports too and a different cable.

Comment: Which port did you try? Try on USB 2.0